# Migrate script from page to js file in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery

I have the following script in `show.html.erb` page, in order to update my progress bar. However it uses jQuery, and since jQuery is just loaded at the end of my `application.html.erb` layout, I cannot use it on my page. So I am requiring it also on my `show.html.erb` page before the script code.

It's clear that this is not the right way to do it. Where should I put my script code so as it's just loaded for this page? Another problem is that it uses information from the controller (`@batch`). If I move it to a js file in my assets folder, how can I access it?

The following code is placed at the end of `show.html.erb`

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
function progress(){
    var progress = setInterval(function() {
      var $bar = $('.bar');
      var $pct = $('#pct');
      $.get("<%= @batch.id %>/status.json", function(data){
        if (data.status == "done") {
          location.reload();
        } else {
          $bar.width(data.progress+"%");
          $pct.text(data.progress+"%");
        }
      });
    }, 800);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get("<%= @batch.id %>/status.json", function(data) {
    if (data.status == "processing") {
      progress();
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

**EDIT**

Since now I'm getting batch_id, I can check if it exists to run the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var batch_id = $("#batch").data("batch-id");
  if (batch_id != null) {
    $.get(batch_id + "/status.json", function(data) {
      if (data.status == "processing") {
        progress();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to handle this is by **unobtrusive javascript** (separate your javascript from html).

First, move the `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` in the `<head>` section of the `application.html.erb` file, so that it properly loads jquery on each page.

Then, move your script inside a js file in your assets directory.

To access the `@batch.id`, add this id inside a data attribute, in your view file (`show.html.erb`).

```
<div id="etc" data-batch-id="<%= @batch.id %>"></div>
```

Then, inside your script:

```
var batch_id = $("#etc").data("batch-id")
$.get(batch_id + "/status.json", ...
```

Comment: Is it Ok for that code to run on every page, even if there is no progress bar? Or should I restrict it to my show view? If I should restrict it, how can I do it? :)

Comment: yes, that should do it. Regarding loading jquery just for this individual page...I don't know what's the best practice to do this. Perhaps it's worth another question